# MongoDB query for getting the latest result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am a novice in Mongo development and I have a collection that has fields such as `id`, `name`, `region`, `more_details`, and `created_at`. I have implemented a cron job to insert new data into this collection every day at 12 AM to keep a history of details. However, when I fetch documents from this collection, I receive all records which is not my requirement. I only require the latest data. How can I implement this using a Mongo query?

I attempted to retrieve the documents using the query:

```
db.collection.find({"region":"asia"}).sort("created_at":-1)
```

However, this query returned all the documents created on different dates. I also attempted to refine the query to

```
db.collection.find({"region":"asia","name":"ramu"}).sort("created_at":-1).limit(1)
```

But this query failed to retrieve all documents that met the specified conditions.

Comment: Can you explain more about how the query failed to retrieve documents, matching the specified conditions

Comment: What all information do you want like ?

Comment: You said in the question, that the second query gave wrong output, can you add some docs, along with what is the expected output and what are you getting

Answer (score 1):

Interpreting *"I only require the latest data."* as just the documents that have `"created_at"` dates of the current day, you could use something like this.

```js
db.collection.find({
  "region": "asia",
  "$expr": {
    "$gte": [
      "$created_at",
      { // truncate $$NOW to beginning of day
        "$dateTrunc": {
          "date": "$$NOW",
          "unit": "day"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/j7h9GR45vVp).